# How to use Hotswap in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, hotswap

How to do that? I can't find any option for it in the IDE... Please help me, I'm clueless.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Run your app in "debug" mode
- Modify your .java files and save them
- Click on the "Apply Code Changes" button that appears on the toolbar (it looks like three linked green rectangles, or Tools -> Options -> Java -> Java Debugger -> General -> Appl code changes after save)

Comment: Hmm, thanks. But it not always work. For example one of methods adds eventlistener to jLabel. So I commented out code that adds it, but then got message: The debugger doesn't support Hot Fix action, details: delete method not implemented. That's when method isn't executed yet (binded it to menu item so I can control when it get executed). When I try this after code execution, details part says "hierarchy change not implemented"

Comment: @DariuszG.Jagielski yeah, you can't add/remove methods/classes (AFAIK). Also, if you change something on your interface, you'd need to reload it in order to see the changes (i.e., it won't "refresh" an opened panel). But you should be able to change the behavior of classes and stuff.

Comment: @DariuszG.Jagielski. Use [dce vm](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/) to be able to add/remove methods and classes.

Comment: @Marcelo. Just wondering how can we do hot swap for the static files like xhtml?