# Netbeans 8.2: Is restarting a project required to see changes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netbeans

I have SpringBoot application in NetBeans 8.2 When it's run I can change content of static .js, .css, etc. files and see changes after web page refresh in browser.

If I change some controller code I need to stop my application and than start it again what is quite annoying.

Is it possible to configure Netbeans to see those changes without restart?

Comment: Sadly not as far as I know. Would be a cool feature though...

Comment: Why are you sticking with netbeans :-), there are other IDEs like sts, Intelij Idea . . .etc which are providing functionality that you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way around it. If you change just a a method body and your application is running in debug mode, you can just apply code changes (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10084388/731178)). This will not work if you modify class structures (new methods, annotations and such).

If you need more, you can use [DCEVM](http://dcevm.github.io/) (for class modifications) or JRebel (commercial, but very capable).

Answer (score 0):

For automatic building and restarting of (Spring Boot) application, please add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```